# xdvipdfmx:fatal: Something is wrong. Are you sure this is a DVI file?

Tags: xetex, dvi, xdvipdfmx

I used to compile my TeX file in Ubuntu 14.04. Recently I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. When I compile my TeX project using `xelatex`, I get the following error:

> xdvipdfmx:fatal: Something is wrong. Are you sure this is a DVI file? Output file removed.
>   Error: Command crashed: "/home/c/linux/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "MyThesis".tex

I run this command:

```
"/path/to/xelatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "MyThesis".
```

but after I added `-no-pdf` to the command, command finished without error. If I run `xdvipdfmx -vv MyThesis.xdv` after that, I get following output again.

```
<FONTMAP:/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map>
<FONTMAP:/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map>
<FONTMAP:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/ckx.map>MyThesis.xdv -> MyThesis.pdf

DVI ID = 5

xdvipdfmx:fatal: Something is wrong. Are you sure this is a DVI file?

Output file removed.
```

Since I'm a TeX novice, please provide some tips to help me solve the problem, if you do know the exact cause of this problem.

Comment: if you use xetex with -no-pdf it should make a `.xdv` file, then run `xdvipdfmx -vv MyThesis.xdv`  so you get the verbose log, it may tell you why it failed....

Comment: Off-topic: Is Ubuntu 16.04 really using TeX Live 2013? Or are you deliberately using an old distribution? Some signficant changes were made in recent years.

Comment: I'm using `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) kpathsea version 6.2.1` the number version is a bit funny :-)

Comment: It looks to me like you have both TeX Live 2013 and 2015 versions, and that you're somehow getting the wrong one when running `xdvipdfmx`. Perhaps removing the 2013 version will help. (I would expect your package manager to have taken care of that during the upgrade. No idea why it didn't, if that is what happened.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen you are RIGHT. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by a clash between two installed TeX Live versions (2013 and 2015).

Comment: Posting this as an answer in order to remove the question from the list of unanswered questions.